# How does XCGLogger interact with classes that implement both CustomStringConvertible and CustomDebugStringConvertible?

Tags: swift, logging, xcglogger

I am trying out XCGLogger and noticed that if I have a logging statement that includes an object instance from a class that implements both CustomDebugStringConvertible and CustomStringConvertible the logger doesn't call the debugDescription property but only seems to invoke the description property from CustomStringConvertible.

My implementation of debugDescription contains additional information over the description property that I would like to be used in logging.

In this situation when both protocols are implemented is their a way to have the logger use debugDescription over description by default?

If only either CustomStringConvertible or CustomDebugStringConvertible is implemented does the logger detect this and use the implemented protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `CustomStringConvertible` or `CustomDebugStringConvertible` is something that happens before the string reaches `XCGLogger`. String interpolation will use the `description` property of `CustomStringConvertible` and not the `debugDescription` property of `CustomDebugStringConvertible`. `debugDescription` is only used when an object conforming to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` is passed to the `debugPrint()` method direction, not inside of quotes.

For example:

```
struct Sample: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "description" }
    var debugDescription: String { return "debugDescription" }
}

let sample = Sample()
print("\(sample)")          // description
debugPrint("\(sample)")     // "description"
print(sample)               // description
debugPrint(sample)          // debugDescription
```

A possible solution for you would be do add `-DDEBUG` to your `Other Swift Flags` (if not already there), and alter your `description` property to be something like this:

```
var description: String {
    #if DEBUG
        return debugDescription
    #else
        return "description"
    #endif
}
```

Then for debug builds, you'll get the `debugDescription` value used in string interpolation, but in your production builds, you'll get your normal `description`.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct, and up vote once you have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Dave Wood's answer, when printing an `Optional` type, I've found that `debugDescription` will be prioritized over `description`

```
struct Sample: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "description" }
    var debugDescription: String { return "debugDescription" }
}

let n: Sample? = Sample()

print(n)                        // Optional(debugDescription)
debugPrint(n)                   // Optional(debugDescription)

print("\(n)")                   // Optional(debugDescription)
debugPrint("\(n)")              // "Optional(debugDescription)"

print(n!)                       // description
debugPrint(n!)                  // debugDescription

print("\(n!)")                  // description
debugPrint("\(n!)")             // "description"

print(String(describing: n))    // Optional(debugDescription)
print(String(reflecting: n))    // Optional(debugDescription)

print(String(describing: n!))   // description
print(String(reflecting: n!))   // debugDescription
```